# Component data not updating in petite-vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, petite-vue

I have a **petite-vue** component with two instances. One works just fine (it only needs to run once, its data is not ever updated), but the other instance does not react as expected when its data changes.

ISSUE: Tracking the updated index of `littleData` works, but using `littleData.data` in a dynamic component does not.

I've read through the [docs for petite-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue?tab=readme-ov-file#comparison-with-standard-vue), but the code below is not working as I expect. Perhaps there is something I'm missing about reactivity (likely).

The code below represents a facsimile of my application. The `setTimeout()` represents changes being made by another block of code in the page outside of petite-vue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Minimum Test 1</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<h2>Minimum Viable Example</h2>
<div v-scope>
    <p>Count: {{Object.keys(bigData).length}}</p>
    <p v-if="littleData.index">Current: {{ littleData.index }}</p> <!-- Simulating other stuff happening in the outer context-->
    <h3>Doesn't update data:</h3>
    <div v-scope="temp1"></div>
</div>
<h3>Data on Creation:</h3>
<div v-scope="temp2"></div>

<template id="my-list-template">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item, key in data" :data-key="key">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script type="module">
import { createApp, reactive } from 'https://unpkg.com/petite-vue?module'

const bigData = {
    1: ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot'],
    2: ['Dog', 'Elephant', 'Ferret'],
    3: ['Hotel', 'Golf', 'India']
}

const littleData = reactive({
    index: null,
    get data() {
        console.log(`... Data fetched at index ${this.index}`)
        return this.index ? bigData[this.index] : null
    }
})

function MyList(props) {
    return {
      $template: '#my-list-template',
      id: props.id || null,
      data: props.data
    }
}

createApp({
    // share it with app scopes
    bigData,
    littleData,
    temp1: MyList({
        data: littleData.data
    }),
    temp2: MyList({
        data: Object.values(bigData).map(i => i[0])
    })
}).mount()

// Imitate outside function modifying values
function rotateIndex() {
    this.next = this.next ? 1 + littleData.index : 1
    
    if (this.next == 4) { //Too high
        this.next = null
    }
    
    console.log(`Rotate! ${this.next} count: ${this.count}`)
    littleData.index = this.next

    this.count = this.count ? 1 + this.count : 1
    if (this.count < 10) { // So this example doesn't go forever
        setTimeout(rotateIndex, 2000)
    }
}

setTimeout(rotateIndex, 2000)
</script>
</html>
```

*(Tagged "vuejs3" because it's similar to "petite-vue")*

Answer (score 0):

After trying several dozen approaches, I can't properly articulate why this works, but it does: I changed the component's `data` prop type from an object to a function. As an object assignment, data appeared to be properly updated in the component (some of the time?) even though it wasn't re-rendering. When `data` is a function, the re-render happens as expected.

*I added this as an answer, because it solves to technical problem, even though it doesn't answer the **why**. I'd appreciate further explanation!*

```html
<template id="my-list-template">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item, key in data()" :data-key="key">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

```js
// ...

createApp({
    bigData,
    littleData,
    temp1: MyList({
        data: () => littleData.data
    }),
    temp2: MyList({
        data: () => Object.values(bigData).map(i => i[0])
    })
}).mount()
```